# participle and modal verbs

Tags: modal-verbs

I am not sure whether participle or gerund of modal verbs is possible in english. For example we have the sentence: Having introduced the speaker, the chairman opened the meeting. What would be the correct form when using the modal verb "must"? Is it "having had to introduce the speaker…"?

Comment: You can simply use *Having to*, e.g. *[Having to act quickly, he grabbed the bust from the window-sill and struck Jason with it, watching as he fell under the desk.](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=uxbQBwv0wH0C&pg=PA231)*

Answer (score 4):

You have it exactly right. The full modals (*can/could,may/might,must,shall/should,will/would*) are 'defective': they have no non-finite forms (participles and infinitives) and do not inflect for person and number. That's one reason why the 'periphrastic modals' like *HAVE to*, *BE going to*, *BE able to* have increased in use over the last couple of centuries.

Comment: +1 :) But, what does 'periphrastic' mean (in this context)?

Comment: @Araucaria: Presumably, the same as it would in any other context *(circumlocutory, using roundabout phrasing)*. Thus, in English, the *past* tense is conveyed using inflection, but the *future* can only be indicated by periphrasis or idiomatically established context (contextual *I am going to die someday*, as opposed to periphrastic *I **will** die*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, suddenly realised I've been reading that for ages but didn't really know exactly what it meant ...

Comment: @Araucaria Most of what schoolteachers call 'tenses' in English - progr - essive, passive, perfect - .are *periphrastic*. It's the old-fashioned term for what is now usually expressed by the *synthetic/analytic* contrast. And the periphrastic modals are those which express the same sense as the ordinary modals by periphrasis.